# Line spacing in wrapped table text

Tags: tables, line-breaking, line-spacing

I have a document where the text is set to double spacing. I have some text inside tables, which I use the paragraphy specifier for. It wraps properly, but spacing is set to single. Is it possible to have the paragraph cells of table be double spaced?

Here's an example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

test

test

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l r r}
\toprule
Item      & 0.5 & 0.2  \\
Something & 0.3 & 34.2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{This should be single spaced.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.25\linewidth} p{0.65\linewidth}}
\toprule
Item      & This is a long line of text that will get wrapped since it doesn't fit
            in the table . It gets wrapped properly, but since it's a paragraph, I
            would like it to have the same spacing as the rest of the document,
            here doublespacing. \\
Something & Blah blah text goes here \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{This should have the paragraph cell double-spaced.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and it gets rendered like this:

[image]

Is there some way to make just paragraphy cells (e.g. `p`, `m`, and `b`) have double spacing while leaving alone the other types of cells?

Preferably, it would be something I could set in my preamble for all tables without having to specify it inline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `\doublespacing` just before `\begin{tabular}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

test

test

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l r r}
\toprule
Item      & 0.5 & 0.2  \\
Something & 0.3 & 34.2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{This should be single spaced.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering\doublespacing
\begin{tabular}{p{0.25\linewidth}p{0.65\linewidth}}
\toprule
Item      & 
This is a long line of text that will get wrapped since it doesn't fit
            in the table . It gets wrapped properly, but since it's a paragraph, I
            would like it to have the same spacing as the rest of the document,
            here doublespacing. \\
Something & Blah blah text goes here \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{This should have the paragraph cell double-spaced.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, it's a little "peculiar" to put your tables inside a `figure` environment,

Comment: any way to do it just for tables with p,b,t and not l,r,c? without have to do it manually?

Comment: lrc columns don't have multiple lines lines so the linespacing can't have any effect on them

Comment: @DavidCarlisle true, but `\doublespacing` will affect the separation between rows.

Comment: @jterrace you can define a new column type: `\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\doublespacing}p{#1}}` and use it instead of `p{...}`, but this won't change the separation between rows.